# How to Solve the error "package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, compiler-errors

```
jagadeesh-Gs-MacBook:Contact jagadeeshgundlapalle$ gradle
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.2.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.4 secs
jagadeesh-Gs-MacBook:Contact jagadeeshgundlapalle$ gradle jar
:compileJava
/Users/jagadeeshgundlapalle/Documents/workspace3/Contact/src/main/java/gurukul/ContactListController.java:4: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                                              ^
/Users/jagadeeshgundlapalle/Documents/workspace3/Contact/src/main/java/gurukul/ContactListController.java:5: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                                              ^
/Users/jagadeeshgundlapalle/Documents/workspace3/Contact/src/main/java/gurukul/ContactListController.java:6: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
                                              ^
/Users/jagadeeshgundlapalle/Documents/workspace3/Contact/src/main/java/gurukul/ContactListController.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol: class RestController
@RestController
 ^
/Users/jagadeeshgundlapalle/Documents/workspace3/Contact/src/main/java/gurukul/ContactListController.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class RequestMapping
location: class gurukul.ContactListController
    @RequestMapping("/getList")
     ^
5 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.53 secs
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 10):

add the spring-web.jar to your dependecies:

```
org.springframework:spring-web:<your spring version>.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when I tried to build a project with spring boot using gradle.
by default the springboot project was created with this reference in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}}
```

Changed this reference:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter
```

for this:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Changed this reference:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter
```

to this:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

It works for me.